# Chaining Dockerfiles - after FROM, running npm no longer works?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm experimenting with docker. I have a simple dockerfile, which includes java and node.

https://github.com/Quafadas/scala-mill

https://github.com/Quafadas/scala-mill/blob/master/Dockerfile

It's published to dockerhub. Now, I'd like to build an application downstream

```
FROM quafadas/scala-mill:latest
RUN java -version
#This doesn't work :-(.
RUN npm --version
```

The command `RUN npm --version` works in the base image linked above, but apparently, not when I'm building on top of it using the `FROM`  directive. Is anyone able to help me understand why?

```
/bin/sh: npm: command not found
15:15:19
      The command '/bin/sh -c npm --version' returned a non-zero code: 127
    enter code here
``
```

Comment: Without knowing what's in that base image, it's really hard to say.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], in particular including the details of the base image?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to have been a few recent commits to the [repo](https://github.com/Quafadas/scala-mill%20https://github.com/Quafadas/scala-mill/blob/master/Dockerfile) which has apparently fixed the issue! I was able to build and run the Dockerfile to get the `npm` version without any issues!

[image]

In case you need additional modules (such as npm) to be installed on a base image that doesn't provide it, use a multi-stage Dockerfile with different `FROM` commands to get your necessary dependencies onto a single Dockerfile and a docker image later. [Reference](https://cloudnweb.dev/2019/10/crafting-multi-stage-builds-with-docker-in-node-js/).